# File permissions on file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, file-permissions

I'm trying to execute a shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

echo VMware Unlocker 1.2.0
echo ===============================
echo Copyright: Dave Parsons 2011-13

# Ensure we only use unmodified commands
export PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin

# Select correct patcher
echo Patching...
ARCH=`uname -m`
if [ "$ARCH" = 'x86_64' ]; then
    ./Unlocker.Linux64
else
    ./Unlocker.Linux32
fi

# Copy darwin.iso to tools folder
cp -v ../Tools/darwin.iso /usr/lib/vmware/isoimages
cp -v ../Tools/darwin.iso.sig /usr/lib/vmware/isoimages

echo Finished!
```

When I try to execute it, it keeps saying:

```
Copyright: Dave Parsons 2011-13
Patching...
install.sh: 15: install.sh: ./Unlocker.Linux64: Permission denied
```

I have tried to set the permissions with both `chown -R` and `chmod 775`, but the permissions doesn't change.

```
drwx------ 1 bryan bryan     384 mar 29 17:44 .
drwx------ 1 bryan bryan     432 mar 29 17:18 ..
-rw------- 1 bryan bryan     508 mar 29 17:44 install.sh
-rw------- 1 bryan bryan     498 sep 19  2013 uninstall.sh
-rw------- 1 bryan bryan 1274692 sep 19  2013 Unlocker.Linux32
-rw------- 1 bryan bryan 1343792 sep 19  2013 Unlocker.Linux64
```

Comment: What is the entire `chmod 775` command that you run?

Comment: @ExplosionPills sudo chmod 775 /media/bryan/6F8F206D0FB07559/Mavericks/Image/Guest_Unlocker/8910/Linux/Unlocker.Linux64

Answer (score 0):

The permissions say you can only read/write to the file, but not execute:

```
chmod +x Unlocker.Linux32 Unlocker.Linux64
```

Comment: I have already tried that to. It still keeps saying that I don't have permissions... It is like the permissions do not apply.

Comment: We need a bit more context. What user are you when you run the script? What if you type `./Unlocker.Linux64` straight from the command line?

Comment: The permissions on `install.sh` are the problem. `chmod +x install.sh`